# Trouble fitting mathematical model to data in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to select the correct mathematical model for my standard curve. This data was collected from spectrophotometry. I am hoping to get a model to help me detect very small absorbance.

```
conc <- c(40, 20, 10, 5, 2.5, 1.25, .3125, .0391)
abs  <- c(.3563333, 0.189333333, .104, 0.061666667, 
          0.039, 0.026666667, 0.018333333, 0.011333333)
```

I can easily fit a linear model to the data, and obtain a $R^2$ value of 0.9995, but, my Y-intercept is equal to -1.9. This becomes a problem when I use this data to find concentrations of my samples, because the linear model gives negative values.

```
plot(abs~conc)
model <- lm(abs~conc)
abline(model)
```

One thing I have noticed, is when transforming the x-axis (concentration in this case), I observe exponential growth. So I try to fit my data to the mathematical model listed below, but the fit is not that great.

```
plot(avg~log(conc))
logconc <- log(conc)
model2  <- nls(avg~a*b^(logconc), start=list(a=.009, b=1))
x       <- seq(-10, 10, .1)
y       <- predict(model2, list(logconc=x))
lines(x,y)
```

I am looking for some advice on a model to apply to this data.

Comment: A quadratic model\* to log-log transformed data seems to do okay, but your models really should come from theoretical considerations. $\quad$ (\* If you had more data, you might be able to support a cubic). If you really have no theoretical basis, and you have enough data (is that all you have?), you might consider a natural spline with say 3 or 4 df.

Comment: I don't any more data for my standard curve.  Basically, I am measuring concentrations of Evans blue extracted from tissue. Also, my concentrations were provided from a serial dilution.

Comment: @Glen_b The log-log analysis has a strong theoretical basis.  To that I would include an *additive offset in the absorbance* to account for a baseline. You will find that an offset of $-0.0104$ works well. There is still some residual curvature that can be interpreted as instrument nonlinearity and modeled quadratically with beautiful results. The last two values will be identified as extreme outliers in this analysis--one high, the other low. That might be the most interesting (and actionable) result to come out of it.

Comment: @whuber thanks - your insights so often show how important subject knowledge can be.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for the comment.  I am curious what an additive offset is?  Would this be my c value in the my equation y=ax+bx^2+c?  Also, should it matter in which way i plot the equation.  It seems that plotting it with abosorbance as the y axis, and concentration as the x axis i get a much better fit than vice versa, and I am not seeing the outliers you mentioned.

Comment: By additive offset to absorbance, @whuber is talking about (in the context of a log-log model) subtracting a constant from absorbance before taking logs. That is, a model of the form $E(\log(\text{abs}-0.0104))=a+b\log(\text{conc})$. He then goes on to talk about adding a quadratic term to that model.

Comment: @Glen_b Actually, I am modeling the opposite relationship, because it appears that the intention is to estimate concentration from observed absorbances. The explanatory terms are linear and quadratic in the adjusted absorbance, $\text{abs}-0.0104$.  It does make (even more) sense to run your model, because presumably the chief errors are in the absorbance, but then one must apply methods of "inverse regression" and "fiducial intervals" to estimate concentrations from future absorbance measurements.

Comment: @whuber I was going by the plot commands used and this lm command: `model <- lm(abs~conc)`. (when first tackling the question because of the 'standard curve' bit I first thought to model it the other way -- and then figured I must have misunderstood something because the OPs models had abs as the y-variable)

Comment: @Glen_b I purposely ignored those. The thinking is that the calibration of this spectrophotometer is a process that will need to be repeated. At this stage, identifying a useful model of its response is the key. To that end, we should construe this as an exploratory exercise and feel free to look at the data as hard as we can, knowing we will subject any preliminary conclusions to testing with the next calibration. The qualitative instrument behavior, then, is of greatest interest: the log-log relationship, the curve at low concentrations, and possibility of outliers in that range.

Comment: In short, MadmanLee, the model @whuber was actually discussing is not as I said earlier, but $E(\log(\text{conc}))=a+b\log(\text{abs}-0.0104)$, and then $E(\log(\text{conc}))=a+b\log(\text{abs}-0.0104)+c\log(\text{abs}-0.0104)^2$. $\ $ It would be good to read all of his comments closely.